# material-ui responsive grid: how to align right and left column to move above middle column on mobile

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have 3 Grid items (see code below); On mobile I would like the left and the right grid item to display above the middle grid item and on tablet view i would like them to display above the middle one and next to eachother. How do i achieve this?

I am using : https://material-ui.com/components/grid/

```
      <Grid item xs={12} md={3} sm={6}>
        <ProductList
          productgroup={this.state.product.group}
          productnumber={this.state.product.number}
          handleProductSelect={this.handleProductSelect}
          productlist={this.props.productlist}
          theme={this.props.selectedTheme} />
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={12} md={6} sm={12}>
        <TableProduct product={this.state.product} parameters={this.state.parameters} />
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={12} md={3} sm={6}>
        <ParameterSelect product={this.state.product} parameters={this.state.parameters} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
      </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer my self in the end by scrolling a lot of stack overflow pages; this is how i implemented it :)

```
  <Grid container direction="row" justify="center" alignItems="center" spacing={3} className={classes.gridWidth}>
          <Box clone order={{ xs: 1, sm: 1, md: 1 }}>
          <Grid item xs={12} md={3} sm={6}>
            <ProductList
              productgroup={this.state.product.group}
              productnumber={this.state.product.number}
              handleProductSelect={this.handleProductSelect}
              productlist={this.props.productlist}
              theme={this.props.selectedTheme} />
            </Grid>
          </Box>
          <Box clone order={{ xs: 3, sm: 3, md: 2 }}>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={6} sm={12}>
            <TableProduct product={this.state.product} parameters={this.state.parameters} />
            </Grid>
          </Box>
          <Box clone order={{ xs: 2, sm: 2, md: 3}}>
          <Grid item xs={12} md={3} sm={6}>
            <ParameterSelect product={this.state.product} parameters={this.state.parameters} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            </Grid>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: do not forget to import: import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'order' prop from [Material UI-V5][1]
Example:

```
    <Grid
      container
      direction="row"
    >
      <Grid item order={{ xs: 2, lg: 1 }}>
        // children comp
      </Grid>

      <Grid item order={{ xs: 1, lg: 2 }}>
        // children comp
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Hope helped you, Thanks !!
[1]: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/